# linux raw socket programming question

Tags: linux, sockets

I am trying to create a raw socket which send and receive message with ip/tcp header under linux.
I can successfully binds to a port and receive tcp message(ie:syn)
However, the message seems to be handled by the os, but not mine. I am just a reader of it(like wireshark).
My raw socket binds to port 8888, and then i try to telnet to that port .
In wireshark, it shows that the port 8888 reply a "rst ack" when it receive the "syn" request. In my program, it shows that it receive a new message and it doesnot reply with any message.

Any way to actually binds to that port?(prevent os handle it)

Here is part of my code, i try to cut those error checking for easy reading

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);

int tmp = 1;
const int *val = &tmp;
setsockopt (sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (tmp));

servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(8888);
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

//call recv in loop
```

Comment: Why do you want to code the actual TCP layer?

Comment: i may need to make change to tcp/ip header in my current project

Comment: I'd google "access tcp header", the first few results should set you in a direction of what functions might be available for that; i don't think "normal" sockets (such as the ones used in beej's guide) are very useful for that

Answer (score 4):

When your kernel receives a SYN/ACK from the remote host, it finds no record of it having sent a SYN to that IP:PORT combination (which was sent from your raw socket) which is why it assumes that there has been an error and sends a RST to the remote host. This problem can be solved by setting up an IP filter that blocks all TCP traffic on that port (Check the iptables manpage for this). That way you don't have to program in kernel space nor will there be any affect on already existing kernel TCP modules.

Answer (score 3):

`man 7 raw` says:

> Raw sockets may tap all IP protocols in Linux, even protocols like ICMP or TCP which have a protocol module in the kernel. In this case the packets are passed to both the kernel module and the raw socket(s).

I take this to mean that you can't "do TCP" on a raw socket without interference from the kernel unless your kernel lacks TCP support -- which, of course, isn't something you want. What raw sockets are good for is implementing other IP protocols that the kernel *doesn't* handle, or for special applications like sending crafted ICMP packets.

Comment: what about using socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP)) instead?
I've read some information that PF_PACKET get packet in data link layer and is it possible to handle the packet there?

Comment: `PF_PACKET` is how pcap is implemented, so I don't think so. Much like AF_INET/SOCK_RAW you can listen to anything you want, and you can send anything you want, but you can't preempt the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

To access raw headers you dont bind a raw socket to a port. Thats not done.

Simply write a sniffer , to "PICK UP" all incoming packets and find out "YOUR" ones. That will also give you access to all of the packets content etc.

This is how you do it :

```
int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ;

while(true)
{
    saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
    //Receive a packet
    data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , &saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
    if(data_size <0 )
    {
        printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //Now process the packet
    ProcessPacket(buffer , data_size);
}
```

In the ProcessPacket function analyse the packet and see if they belong to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: 
In case you intend to program raw sockets, check [this](http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html).

It has a few examples of how to send and receive raw packets.

In case you want to use `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_SEQPACKET` connection-oriented type sockets:

You need to tell it to listen after binding to a given address:port.

```
int connectionQueue = 10;
if ( -1 == listen(sockfd, connectionQueue) )
{
  // Error occurred
}
```

Afterwards, you will need to verify the descriptor for incoming connections using select, and accept an incoming connection on either the server socket (which will lead to not accepting new connections), or a dedicated client socket.

Comment: Beej's guide is a very good beginner resource for him http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html

Comment: @laura: +1 for the reference, was looking for that :-)

Comment: I've just tried to add these lines after the bind function, but it just have error
OS error code  95:  Operation not supported

Comment: listen is not valid for a raw socket; it only works for stream sockets.